# Generated column (row_number) in Flask SQL-Alchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to have a additional property on my object-relationship-mapped object.

I need to have a property that is calculated at the database using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

My Class looks something like this:

```py
class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I think I need to use the `hybrid_property` for this. I don't know to define the property but I think I have an idea about the expression:

```py
class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def group_specific_id(self):
        # no idea what to put here
        pass
    
    @group_specific_id.expression
    def project_specific_id(cls):
        return db.session.query(func.row_number().over(partition_by=cls.group_id))
```

Am I on the right path? Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

This definition should work for you:

```py
class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def group_specific_id(self):
        return db.session.query(func.row_number().over(partition_by=self.group_id))
    
    @group_specific_id.expression
    def group_specific_id(cls):
        return db.session.query(func.row_number().over(partition_by=cls.group_id))
```

And now you can use hybrid property like that:

```py
example = Example(group_id=2)
example.group_specific_id
```

or like an expression

```py
examples = session.query(Example).filter(Example.group_specific_id == <smth>)
```